# NameError: global name is not defined when calling function from another python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, automation

I am trying to call a function that exists in another python file and pass it user input from the current python file that is running. I keep getting the 
error:

> "NameError: global name 'main1' is not defined."

This is my first time writing in python and first time posting to stack overflow so forgive me but I am unsure as to what to include in this post. I am also using `Tkinter` in one file and `pdf miner` for the other two and my `python version 2.7` (outdated I know).

I have tried renaming the main function being called to not confuse it with functions from the other possible file to be called, creating an **Init**.py file, marking folders as a source since I am using `pycharm`, importing the `.py` files in different ways.

```
from DearNeighbor import *
from NameOnPage import *
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
from functools import partial
import Tkinter as tk
```

`DearNeighbor` is the file that contains `main1` and `NameOnPage` is the file that contains `main2`.

The function I'm trying to Run:

```
def submit():
    if BoolNeighbor:
        main1(txt0, pdf0)
    if BoolName:
        main2(txt1, pdf1)
```

the `txt` and `pdf` files being passed are two strings that are the addresses of the files to be looked at.

Main1 in DearNeighbor:

```
def main1(textinput, pdfinput):
    start_time = time.time()
    global txt00
    global pdf00
    txt00 = textinput
    pdf00 = pdfinput
    pdf_dict = pdf_records_file()
    text_dict = records_in_text_file()
    different = set()
    count = 0
    for key in sorted(set(pdf_dict.keys()) & set(text_dict.keys())):
        pdf_value = [x.upper() for x in pdf_dict[key]]
        text_value = [x.upper() for x in text_dict[key]]
        if pdf_value == text_value:
            count += 1
            print()
            print(key, "from pdf file", pdf_dict[key], colored("MATCHED", 'green', attrs=['bold']), key, "from text file", text_dict[key])
            print()
        else:
            different.add(key)
            print(key, "from pdf file", pdf_dict[key], colored("DID NOT MATCH", 'red', attrs=['bold']), key, "from text file", text_dict[key])
            print()

    print()
    print("The number of records matched = ", colored(count, 'yellow',attrs=['bold']))
    print()
    print("Total time taken = ", colored(" %s seconds", 'yellow') % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The full error printed is:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/will.rogers/Desktop/Python Scripts/ExecutableAutomation/venv/FrontEnd.py", line 69, in submit
    main1(txt0, pdf0)
NameError: global name 'main1' is not defined
```

the rest of the code in this program is building a user interface in tkinter that is basically a bunch of (working) buttons that lead to the submit function and no error occurs up until it. I hope this was enough information, Thanks!

Comment: Use explicit ``from DearNeighbor import main1`` instead of catch-all ``from DearNeighbor import *`` to catch failing imports early.

Comment: In what file is the snippet of code that calls `main1` and `make2`?

Comment: @Oerd it's in a file called FrontEnd and it calls from either DearNeighbor(main1) or NameOnPage(main2) respectively from two mutually exclusive boolean values.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Hi, when I do that I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name main1". Any clue as to why?

Comment: Contrary to what you think, ``DearNeighbor `` does *not* define ``main1``. Perhaps a typo? We cannot tell without code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi weird, I'm not sure what code you need to see but the function code from DearNeighbor.py is: `def main1(textinput, pdfinput):`
    Edit: I had pasted more code but it made a hard to read comment sorry I can only paste this much.

Comment: Keep in mind that Python doesn't have process-wide globals, only module-level globals. You really need to provide a complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem, which will probably demonstrate that something is trying to access another module's global variable "locally".

Comment: @chepner thank you, that's helpful to know! if that's my issue how could I go about fixing it?

Comment: @btkidd98 You might want to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Basically copy and trim down your code until it contains no unrelated details, but enough to replicate the issue. For example, we don't need the ``Tkinter`` import. We do need the definition of ``main1`` in ``DearNeighbor.py``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added the function of Main1, I believe that should be enough to reproduce it. If it's not I'll try and add more. Thanks and I appreciate you helping!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the comments! you guys pointed me in the right direction and I appreciate it. I was importing FrontEnd in the class I wanted FrontEnd to import and that caused some issues. I then got an exception where it wanted Unicode and I gave it 'str'. I fixed that by upgrading to Python 3.7 (which I wasn't technically supposed to do but 2.7 was giving me so many issues I couldn't resist. special thanks to @MisterMiyagi in the comments, I wouldn't have noticed without his help!

Comment: If someone has a reason as to why that import messed it up I'd appreciate the explanation because I don't know python well.

Comment: Did you use a cyclic import perhaps? FrontEnd -> DearNeighbor -> Frontend?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, that was my issue.